# How do I preview my camera app on phone using ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Im currently developing a camera app using ionic2 for my school project. However, I am unable to find a way to preview the camera app. I have tried previewing it on android studio and web browser but not able to do so.

Please help!!

Here is my code

Home.html

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>
            Ionic 2 Camera
        </ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
    <button ion-button color="dark" (click)="takePhoto()">Take Photo</button>
    <img [src]="imageURL" *ngIf="imageURL" />
    </ion-content>
```

Home.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Camera} from "@ionic-native/camera";

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    selector:'page.home'
})
export class HomePage {
  Camera: any;
  imageURL
  constructor() {}
  takePhoto(){
    this.Camera.getPicture().then((imageData) => {
       this.imageURL = imageData
    }, (err) => {
       console.log(err);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please do console.log(imageData) in camera success callback?

Comment: Have changed it but still unable to take picture nor preview

Comment: export class HomePage {
  Camera: any;
  imageURL
  constructor() {}
  takePhoto(){
    this.Camera.getPicture().then((imageData) => {
       this.imageURL = imageData;
       console.log(imageData);
    }, (err) => {
       console.log(err);
    });
  }
}

Comment: Camera is starting successfully or not?

Comment: not successful, tried to preview in web browser and android studio but cannot start camera.

Comment: update:camera is working

Comment: ok so everything is working fine?